# dwarf debug info missing data on constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor, dwarf

Im looking at a dwarf file generated from a c++ files and I noticed that it is not showing any info on one of the constructors. Here is my c++ file -

```
class C {
public:
    C();
    C(int x, int y);
    int getX();
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class SubC : public C {
    int z;
};

int f() {return 0;}

C c;
SubC subC;

int i;
double d;
```

And here is my dwarf file -

```
The section .debug_info contains:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x134 (32-bit)
   Version:       2
   Abbrev Offset: 0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0xd): GNU C++ 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)  
    <10>   DW_AT_language    : 4    (C++)
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x75): test.cpp    
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x4d): /home/dwarf 
    <19>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0  
    <21>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xb  
    <29>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0  
 <1><2d>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_class_type)
    <2e>   DW_AT_name        : C    
    <30>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8    
    <31>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <32>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1    
    <33>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x86>   
 <2><37>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <38>   DW_AT_name        : x    
    <3a>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <3b>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 7    
    <3c>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <40>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 0   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 0)
    <43>   DW_AT_accessibility: 3   (private)
 <2><44>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <45>   DW_AT_name        : y    
    <47>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <48>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 8    
    <49>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <4d>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 4   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 4)
    <50>   DW_AT_accessibility: 3   (private)
 <2><51>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <52>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <53>   DW_AT_name        : C    
    <55>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <56>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4    
    <57>   DW_AT_declaration : 1    
    <58>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x6d>   
 <3><5c>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <5d>   DW_AT_type        : <0x8d>   
    <61>   DW_AT_artificial  : 1    
 <3><62>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <63>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
 <3><67>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <68>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
 <2><6d>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <6e>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <6f>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x70): getX    
    <73>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <74>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 5    
    <75>   DW_AT_MIPS_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x0): _ZN1C4getXEv    
    <79>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <7d>   DW_AT_declaration : 1    
 <3><7e>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <7f>   DW_AT_type        : <0x8d>   
    <83>   DW_AT_artificial  : 1    
 <1><86>: Abbrev Number: 8 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <87>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 4    
    <88>   DW_AT_encoding    : 5    (signed)
    <89>   DW_AT_name        : int  
 <1><8d>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
    <8e>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8    
    <8f>   DW_AT_type        : <0x2d>   
 <1><93>: Abbrev Number: 10 (DW_TAG_class_type)
    <94>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x41): SubC    
    <98>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 12   
    <99>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <9a>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 11   
    <9b>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xb6>   
 <2><9f>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_inheritance)
    <a0>   DW_AT_type        : <0x2d>   
    <a4>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 0   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 0)
    <a7>   DW_AT_accessibility: 1   (public)
 <2><a8>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <a9>   DW_AT_name        : z    
    <ab>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <ac>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 12   
    <ad>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <b1>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 8   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 8)
    <b4>   DW_AT_accessibility: 3   (private)
 <1><b6>: Abbrev Number: 12 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <b7>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <b8>   DW_AT_name        : f    
    <ba>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <bb>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 15   
    <bc>   DW_AT_MIPS_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x36): _Z1fv  
    <c0>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <c4>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0  
    <cc>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xb  
    <d4>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x0  (location list)
 <1><d8>: Abbrev Number: 13 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <d9>   DW_AT_name        : c    
    <db>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <dc>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 17   
    <dd>   DW_AT_type        : <0x8d>   
    <e1>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <e2>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  (DW_OP_addr: 0)
 <1><ec>: Abbrev Number: 14 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <ed>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x3c): subC    
    <f1>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <f2>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 18   
    <f3>   DW_AT_type        : <0x102>  
    <f7>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <f8>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  (DW_OP_addr: 8)
 <1><102>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
    <103>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8   
    <104>   DW_AT_type        : <0x93>  
 <1><108>: Abbrev Number: 13 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <109>   DW_AT_name        : i   
    <10b>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1   
    <10c>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 20  
    <10d>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>  
    <111>   DW_AT_external    : 1   
    <112>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    (DW_OP_addr: 10)
 <1><11c>: Abbrev Number: 13 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <11d>   DW_AT_name        : d   
    <11f>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1   
    <120>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 21  
    <121>   DW_AT_type        : <0x130> 
    <125>   DW_AT_external    : 1   
    <126>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    (DW_OP_addr: 18)
 <1><130>: Abbrev Number: 15 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <131>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8   
    <132>   DW_AT_encoding    : 4   (float)
    <133>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x46): double
```

The key section is the following -

```
<1><2d>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_class_type)
    <2e>   DW_AT_name        : C    
    <30>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8    
    <31>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <32>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1    
    <33>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x86>   
 <2><37>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <38>   DW_AT_name        : x    
    <3a>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <3b>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 7    
    <3c>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <40>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 0   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 0)
    <43>   DW_AT_accessibility: 3   (private)
 <2><44>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_member)
    <45>   DW_AT_name        : y    
    <47>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <48>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 8    
    <49>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <4d>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 4   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 4)
    <50>   DW_AT_accessibility: 3   (private)
 <2><51>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <52>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <53>   DW_AT_name        : C    
    <55>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <56>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4    
    <57>   DW_AT_declaration : 1    
    <58>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x6d>   
 <3><5c>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <5d>   DW_AT_type        : <0x8d>   
    <61>   DW_AT_artificial  : 1    
 <3><62>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <63>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
 <3><67>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <68>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
 <2><6d>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <6e>   DW_AT_external    : 1    
    <6f>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x70): getX    
    <73>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1    
    <74>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 5    
    <75>   DW_AT_MIPS_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x0): _ZN1C4getXEv    
    <79>   DW_AT_type        : <0x86>   
    <7d>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
```

This section contains info about the class C, including the constructor that takes 2 ints and the function after the constructors, but nothing about the default constructor. Why is that? I have another dwarf file on an almost identical c++ file (the two int constructor is a one int constructor) which *does* show info about the default constructor, so how come the info isnt in both files? Note: the other file was compiled with a slightly different compiler.

Edit: Incase you were curious, the commands I used to generate the dwarf file were - `g++ -g -c test.cpp -o test.o` and then `readelf --debug-dump=info >test.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different questions I have about this.  If your constructor C::C(void) is implemented in source code (instead of a trivial one synthesized by the compiler), I'd expect to see it described in the DWARF, if for no other reason than you may step in to this function and you'll want to see symbolic information about the arguments and blocks of your method.  If C::C(void) is the one provided by the compiler, I don't know if I'd flag it as a bug that it isn't mentioned in the DWARF.

Many compilers also try to remove unused types from the DWARF to reduce the size of the debug information.  You declare C::C(int,int) but don't define/call it.  I'm sure that's just because this is a small example bit of code - but still, keep in mind that if the compiler thinks C::C(int,int) is undefined/unused, it may choose to omit it from the debug information.  Sometimes these unused-types reduction schemes also have bugs in them and they omit information that really should have been included.  These kinds of toy example compilation units can result in especially unexpected debug information when the compiler does unused type removal.

For what it's worth, running your example compilation unit through clang produces the following dwarf (this is output by `dwarfdump` on Mac OS X - it omits the `DW_` prefix on names which is a little odd but otherwise it's readable enough.)

```
0x00000032:     TAG_class_type [4] *
                 AT_name( "C" )
                 AT_byte_size( 0x08 )
                 AT_decl_file( "/private/tmp/b.cc" )
                 AT_decl_line( 1 )

0x0000003a:         TAG_member [5]  
                     AT_name( "x" )
                     AT_type( {0x00000026} ( int ) )
                     AT_decl_file( "/private/tmp/b.cc" )
                     AT_decl_line( 7 )
                     AT_data_member_location( +0 )
                     AT_accessibility( DW_ACCESS_private )

0x00000049:         TAG_member [5]  
                     AT_name( "y" )
                     AT_type( {0x00000026} ( int ) )
                     AT_decl_file( "/private/tmp/b.cc" )
                     AT_decl_line( 8 )
                     AT_data_member_location( +4 )
                     AT_accessibility( DW_ACCESS_private )

0x00000058:         TAG_subprogram [6] *
                     AT_name( "C" )
                     AT_decl_file( "/private/tmp/b.cc" )
                     AT_decl_line( 3 )
                     AT_declaration( 0x01 )
                     AT_external( 0x01 )
                     AT_accessibility( DW_ACCESS_public )

0x00000062:             TAG_formal_parameter [7]  
                         AT_type( {0x0000002d} ( C* ) )
                         AT_artificial( 0x01 )

0x00000068:             NULL

0x00000069:         TAG_subprogram [6] *
                     AT_name( "C" )
                     AT_decl_file( "/private/tmp/b.cc" )
                     AT_decl_line( 4 )
                     AT_declaration( 0x01 )
                     AT_external( 0x01 )
                     AT_accessibility( DW_ACCESS_public )

0x00000073:             TAG_formal_parameter [7]  
                         AT_type( {0x0000002d} ( C* ) )
                         AT_artificial( 0x01 )

0x00000079:             TAG_formal_parameter [8]  
                         AT_type( {0x00000026} ( int ) )

0x0000007e:             TAG_formal_parameter [8]  
                         AT_type( {0x00000026} ( int ) )

0x00000083:             NULL
```

Comment: Well then things get even odder... I do technically call the default constructor when I declare `C c`, and I *never* call the `C(int, int)` constructor. Yet for some reason the `C(int, int)` is defined in the Dwarf and the `C()` is not. Would changing optimizer setting change how the Dwarf file looks in the end? Perhaps the `C()` wont get cut off?

Comment: It's not what I'd expect either -- but I'd be careful about drawing conclusions from toy sample compilation units if your compiler may be doing type duplication elimination.  Read through your compiler's command line arguments to see how to turn those off.  It's like creating a test program that does something like `char getChar () { return "hello"[2]; }` and being surprised that the compiler didn't emit `"hello"` anywhere in the program -- a compiler would have to go out of its way to not just return the constant 108 (`'l'`).